Can't import the named export '$applyNodeReplacement'
I upgraded my lexical version from 12 to 16 and boom. It is breaking now
./node_modules//node_modules/@lexical/list/LexicalList.dev.mjs
Can't import the named export '$applyNodeReplacement' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
I am not using vite instead I am using create react app. Any workaround for this issue?
